# Proving or disproving two sentences using limit arithmetics

Tags: real-analysis, limits

These are the questions:

1. if $\lim \limits _{x \to x_0} (f(x) - g(x)) = 0$ then $\lim \limits _{x \to x_0} (f^2 (x) - g^2 (x)) = 0$;
2. if $\lim \limits _{x \to x_0} |f(x) = L$, then $\lim \limits _{x \to x_0} f(x)$ exists and is equal to either $L$ or $-L$.

I want to check myself and see if I am right. I'm thinking 1. is true and the proof is pretty simple: using limits aritmethics, $f(x) f(x)$ is still, same with $g(x) g(x)$, and then subtracting the result.

For 2., I think it's false. Counter example: $f(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 1, & x \ge 0 \\ -2, & x < 0 \end{matrix} \right.$; that way, if $x_0 = -1$ then $|f(x)| = L = 1$ but $f(x) = -2$, not $L$.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:** For the first one, you must be careful; just because $\lim [f(x)-g(x)]=0$ does not mean $\lim f(x)=\lim g(x)$ as it might be the case that neither limit exists (take $\sin(1/x)$ for an example). Try to find an example where $f(x)+g(x)\to\infty$ "faster" than $f(x)-g(x)\to0$. As a remark, this statement becomes true if you know that either $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$ (as then the limit exists for both functions).

The second one is false, but not for the reasons you have stated (e.g., you write $|f(x)|=L=-1$ which immediately is false since $|x|\geq0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$). You are on the right track, though; think of $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&:x>0\\-1&:x\leq0\end{cases}.$$ Then $|f(x)|=1$ for all $x$, but it isn't continuous.

Comment: Of course, the first statement is also true if $f+g$ is bounded.  This is the case even if neither is continuous and even if $\lim (f+g)$ doesn't exist since $|f^2-g^2|=|f-g|\,|f+g|\le B|f-g|$, where $B$ bounds $f+g$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- for the first, this is actually false. Start with $f^2(x)-g^2(x) = (f(x)-g(x))(f(x)+g(x))$. You know that $f(x)-g(x)\xrightarrow[x\to x_0]{}0$, but what if $f(x)+g(x)\xrightarrow[x\to x_0]{}\infty$? (Then, you have a limit of the form $0\cdot \infty$, which can lead to basically anything.)

  > E.g., take $f(x) = \frac{1}{(x-x_0)^2}$ and $g(x)=f(x)+(x-x_0)^2$. What is the limit?
- For the second, you are on the right track (this is indeed false). Try to see if you can have $f(x)$ "oscillate" between $-L$ and $L$ as $x\to x_0$.

  > The simplest, as you seem to suggest, is to have only two values for $f(x)$. $f(x) = -L$ if $x< x_0$, and $f(x)=L$ if $x\geq x_0$.